# Add more than one parameter to a FilterString

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

Trying to add more than one parameter to a filter string.

This works fine...

```
DeliveryTransactions.FilterString = "[IngredientName] = [Parameters.Ingredient]";
```

BUT, I would like to add another string

```
[LocationName] = [Parameters.Location]
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `And` to combine multiple conditions or `Or` depending on your requirement.

```
DeliveryTransactions.FilterString = "[IngredientName] = [Parameters.Ingredient] And [LocationName] = [Parameters.Location]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `And` or `Or`

BTW, a great way to learn this for beginners is by using the FilterControl:

http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/filtering/FilterBuilder.aspx